# Get file size from text file

Tags: c#

Trying to get the file size from a list then output the results to a text file. At present I have been able to get the first half working of reading from a file checking if the file exists and then outputting to console and textfile

I am new programming "Just started this week". This may be any easy question and tried but cant quite get it working

I have tried putting this inside the foreach loop and trying to read path but it isnt working.

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
```

My code so far

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Locations2.txt");
        foreach (string path in lines)
            if (File.Exists(path))
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Results.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("File found" + "\t" + path);
                    Console.WriteLine("File found" + "\t" + path);
                }


            else
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Results.txt", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine("Does not Exist" + "\t" + path);
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Exist" + "\t" + path);
                }

    }
```

Thankyou in advance and if this in badly code can you advise why it should not be done this way?

Comment: Hint: PLace the file creation/open outside the for loop....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get information about a file -- including its size -- with the `FileInfo` class

e.g.

```
var fileName = @"C:\Locations2.txt";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
var size = fi.Length;
Console.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
```

The code you had above that you put inside the loop is the right concept, just the wrong implementation.  If you know the file name you want to open, no need to go through the `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` route.  Just access the `FileInfo` directly.

So your code would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Locations2.txt");
    foreach (string path in lines)
        if (File.Exists(path))
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Results.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("File found" + "\t" + path);
                Console.WriteLine("File found" + "\t" + path);

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
                var size = fi.Length;
                file.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
                Console.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
            }


        else
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Results.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Does not Exist" + "\t" + path);
                Console.WriteLine("Does not Exist" + "\t" + path);
            }

}
```

Comment: this would only find for that one filename. Inside C:\Locations2.txt is a list of locations, these locations need to be passed to find the file size of these for example on a new line in the file locations2.txt it would have "c:\1.txt, c:\2.txt, c:\3.txt"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Can you give us sample of what's inside Locations2.txt ?  Show us some output?  Please modify your question with this additional information.

Comment: "c:\1.txt, c:\2.txt, c:\3.txt" each path on a new line

Comment: I modified my answer to be more explicit.  See the 4 lines I added to the `if(FileExists)` branch.  Given `path`, it creates a `FileInfo` then gets the length and logs it to the file and to the Console.

Comment: Thankyou very much solved it for me. I knew it would have been simple.